# Explaining the memory usage pattern of a multiprocessing pool used for ETL

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I am using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) for an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) processing of several thousands parquet files. Each worker applies a processing function on the parquet and returns the processing result to the main process which aggregates data from all workers.

The pool is configured with 16 workers and `maxtasksperchild=1`

I measured the ram usage and observed a rather unusual pattern:
[image: ram]

It's not clear to me what causes those momentary spikes which tend to grow (enveloped by the blue line). I would've expected a small growth due to the memory used by the main process to aggregated worker data (green envelope).

Since the bottleneck of the entire processing is loading the parquet data (using [`pandas.read_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html)), the spikes may be due to all workers loading the data simultaneously. However, this does not explain the increasing envelope of the spikes. All the parquet files close to identical sizes, so the spikes' height shouldn't grow.

Further debugging showed that this pattern is visible for other values of `maxtasksperchild` as well, **apart from** `maxtasksperchild=None` (so worker processes will live as long as the pool). The memory pattern no longer indicates spikes:
[image: ram2]

My question is what's causing the spikes and their growth, when `maxtasksperchild` is not None?

Comment: So, can you elaborate on precisely what information is on being graphed? What did you do with the output of `free`?

Comment: This was the only process running on my machine, so I wrote a script to dump `free`'s output to a file and subtracted the baseline value before the process started.

Comment: what exactly from frees output? how does that account for buff/cache?

Comment: I extracted the used memory.

Comment: Did you subtract the `buff/cached`? You only want memory used by the process. Let me put it this way, `free`'s output is a 2 by 7 matrix of values (the dimensions might be different with different implementations). What exactly did you extract?

Comment: No, I did not subtract it, only the raw `used` value. I understand my mistake now. If `used` contains `buff/cached`, those spikes can actually mean that data is being cached over the course of the processing. Is this correct?

Comment: So, [`used = total - free - cached - buffers`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770108/what-do-the-changes-in-free-output-from-14-04-to-16-04-mean)

Comment: Well, the OS is using it for the caching for it's own business. It's not data is that is being explicitly used by your process. If active processes request memory, the OS handles freeing the cache to accomodate those requests

Comment: Got it, valid points, thank you! Will use a different approach for the measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Following [@juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) comments, I understand the potential caveats of naively using `free` to track memory usage. To this extent, I switched to using [`mprof`](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), configured to include memory usage of the child processes, as well as track each one separately:

```
mprof run --include-children --multiprocess <cmd>
```

The output looks like this:
[image]